# Tridion R5 event system

Tags: event-system, r5

I am writing event code for Tridion R5 in C# but i am facing some challenges while implementing it in tridion. 
Is there any reference for Tridion R5 event system documentation or some sample code i can have?

Thanks

Comment: R5 are Visual Basic event systems, if you are using R5.3 you can use the TOM.NET interop (officially it was still only VB), so perhaps you can be a bit more specific on what version of Tridion you are exactly using?
Please note that any of the R5 versions are end-of-life, so you shouldn't really be developing new stuff on it...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bart. I am using Tridion R5.3 and just firing a simple event using C#. Is it possible to write event system code using C# in Tridion R5.3 or VB is the only option to write event code in Tridion R5.3. Any reference documentation will be of much helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your 5.3 event system in C# as long as you make it Com-compatible (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx).

Register it with regasm.

In your class, you can use the Tridion Interops to access the TOM.

Answer (score 2):

From a [very old thread](https://forum.tridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=6644) on a very old (closed) forum...

> If you do the following, Visual Studio will complete it for you:

1. Add references to `Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.cm_tom.dll`, `Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.cm_defines.dll` and `Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.msxml4.dll`
2. In your code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDSDefines;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.msxml4;

namespace yourNamespace.goes.here
{
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ProgId("TDSEvents.Events")]
  public sealed class Events : ITCMEvents
```

> 3. At this point Visual Studio will propose that you press TAB and it will create all the methods for you.

Be aware that events that happen to use MSXML2 objects will cause problems in .NET due to serialization issues between COM and .NET, unless you're running on .NET 1.1 (which I seriously doubt).

Comment: To add to this great answer, please note that when using COM through .NET you get a lot of potential (memory related) issues if not done correctly. Check out [my answer here](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/event-system-alternatives-memory-leakage#1216) for some details on how to release these COM objects properly.

Comment: Hi, I have added all the references given above in Step 1 and step 2 is also done. I am running my application with .Net 2.0 framework.

Comment: And is it working? Where are you stuck now?

Comment: +1 to Bart for pointing out the pitfalls of COM interop in .Net. Prepare to write Marshal.ReleaseComObject very, very often....